# Has anyone created an Android app with embedded flash/.swf files such as animations?

Tags: android, flash

I understand that flash is quite new to android. Has anyone actually used flash in an android app? How did you do it and what do you recommend. I'm trying to embed flash animation into an app if that helps any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always convert the Flash file into a video or gif, and then place it into your app.

If you don't necessarily need to use flash, other software or editing with code in your app might be a good idea too..

This link might be useful: http://www.ehow.com/way_6175136_android-animation-tutorial.html

Comment: That's a tutorial, or rather three-paragraph summary, on how to animate an Android... ?